# Multiple scrolling panes in a window without jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

So, I'm faced with a dilemma of putting together a 3 column layout that has three independently scrolling panes.  With a combination of the right HTML, CSS and jQuery, I can achieve the following (Fiddle link opens to another window, jQuery is below):

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/699mruxd/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doResize();
});

// for the window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    doResize();
});

function doResize() {
    var bodyheight = $(document).height();
    $(".left").height(bodyheight);
    $(".right").height(bodyheight);
    $(".center").height(bodyheight);
}
```

The question is, can this be done without using jQuery to get the exact result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add `height: 100%;` to each pane? Here is the same example with no JavaScript

```
.left, .center, .right {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qjtoaqko/)

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't work previously for me, but thank you.